# What are some typical design patterns when using the Canvas API?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, design-patterns, html5-canvas

I'm starting to get into graphical programming using the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), but I haven't seen any design patterns for reusing canvas code. So far I've only seen examples using a global canvas object and a single draw function.

I'm coming from a Python tkinter background where the primary pattern is to have a class for each graphical object, and pass the canvas context into the constructor so the object can draw itself. I was thinking about using the module pattern below to achieve the same thing, but I'm looking for more of a JavaScript way if there is one.

```
var MyShape = function (ctx) {
    // Assign the canvas context along with any other properties,
    // then draw the object.
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.draw();
}

MyShape.prototype.draw = function () {
    // Use this.ctx to access the Canvas API and draw the object.
}
```

Comment: Have you already had a look at paperjs.org? This is an OO library, which renders on the canvas...

Comment: Your pattern appears to be fine and quite standard (not only for Python but also in JS). For additional flexibility, pass the context to the `draw` method instead of storing it as an instance property.

Comment: @Bergi I hadn't thought of passing the context directly into the draw function, and I was considering it until Shadetheartist reminded me that I'd typically use an update function in this situation that also needs access to the context.

Comment: @Nocturno Why would `update` need the canvas context? It certainly needs some kind of scene context (locations of other objects, map boundaries, etc) and the current time, but it doesn't need to draw anything.

Comment: @Bergie I don't know, I was hoping you guys would tell me that! Seriously though, In my experience I've had times when an object redraws itself for one reason or another. Say when a ball hits a wall, and the ball changes shape in reaction to it bouncing back, or maybe when one of these graphical objects acts as the view for a model, and redraws parts of itself when that model changes.

Comment: @noct no you dont want the context anywhere near the update function. What you want to do is change the state of the object in such a way that when the render is called the changes are made then. Stuff like rotation and position are simple and common examples of a change in object state that is reflected when rendering.

Always remember not to cross those streams. It should always be Update -> Render (in that order) in a loop. So all the updating is done while the last frame is on the canvas, then all at once everything in your program is rendered.

Comment: @noct A cool trick is to just replace the render function entirely, that way you don't need a million conditionals littered everywhere. If you look at some of the old crappy code i did for [avalanche](http://quadrilation.com/random/games/Ablockalypse/js/player.js) you will notice that there are a playerRender and playerJumpRender functions defined. And i set the player's instance render function to one of those when it made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea so far. In addition to what you have, i suggest you include an update function to each defined renderable object. So long as there's a possibility that these shapes may be moving over time.

Also, if you find yourself needing more complex shapes, I suggest you compose your complex shapes out of other shape classes you have already defined. Such as a smiley face shape that, in its draw function, uses three predefined circle classes for the eyes and head, and perhaps just use the canvas context to generate the smile.

You would call the draw function of each child shape from the parent shape in a cascade of draw calls.

**Edit**: Here's a little example, i forgot to mention the importance of using a reference type to store the position of the parent of the shapes.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
 var thing = new Thing(100, 100, 30, 40);

function Vector(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }
 
 function Rectangle(pos, w, h, color, parent){
  //use a vector2 'pos' so that the position of this rectangle matches the position of the parent
  //because pos is a reference type
  this.pos = pos;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.color = color || '#000';
 }
 
 Rectangle.prototype.render = function(){
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.w, this.h);
 };
 
 function Circle(pos, r, color, parent){
  //use a vector2 'pos' so that the position of this circle matches the position of the parent
  //because pos is a reference type
  this.pos = pos;
  this.r = r;
  this.color = color || '#000';
 }
 
 Circle.prototype.render = function(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fill();
 };
 
 function Thing(x, y, w, h){
  //create pos reference
  this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
  
  //use pos reference
  this.rect = new Rectangle(this.pos, w, h, '#00F');
  this.circle = new Circle(this.pos, w, '#F00');
  
  //for update() demonstration
  this.rotation = 0;
 }
 
 Thing.prototype.render = function(){
  this.circle.render();
  this.rect.render();
 };
 
 Thing.prototype.update = function(){
  //notice here i only have to modify the values of pos.x and pox.y, this is important
  //because if i had added fields x and y to the Thing class, they would not be reference types 
  //and i could not have moved both the rectangle and the circle if that was the case.
  this.pos.x = this.pos.x + Math.cos(this.rotation);
  this.pos.y = this.pos.y + Math.sin(this.rotation);
  this.rotation += 0.02;
 };

 function update(){
  thing.update();
 }
  
 function render(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  thing.render();
 }
 
 function main(){
  update();
  render();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
 }
 
 main();
```

```css
#game{
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's a very common pattern in web game design i believe. At least at the level i was working at.

Comment: Great example! This is basically what I had in mind, and it makes it easy to break up code into reusable modules. My only question is about the way you reference `ctx` inside these modules. I tend to think of a module as a black box that shouldn't know about the existence of anything outside of it, unless you explicitly pass it in. Is there a benefit to accessing `ctx` as a global from inside these modules?

Comment: @Nocturno I _could_ have made some sort of container for the scene or game that had a reference to the canvas and the context and then all the stuff basically goes in there. But from my personal experience making [web games](http://quadrilation.com/random/games/Ablockalypse/) i prefered ctx to be global because you do kinda need it everywhere. 

So it was a trade of bad practice for real world practicality. Which i am very strict about.

Answer (score 0):

### Modular design.

It seems that the way forward for javascript in regards to building tools, interfaces (programmatic), frameworks libraries and what nots is modular.

Javascript has never been a link library type of language, its structure is very haphazard and there are no real scope protection mechanisms that can be relied upon to resolve namespace conflict, availability, context targeting, and more.

Javascript relies on a set of loose conventions, agreed upon by popular vote of use rather than a debated, quantified, amended...  standard.

With that is the modular approch. Discrete components are defined and added to an  agreed registry space. You create a namespace via a function and ensure you keep out of the global scope.

**Node.JS and the simple Module**

NodeJs is an example of modular design with components and interfaces as modules that are accessed via a simple `required` interface. This will load and return a referance to the required module.

example loading a module in NodeJS

```
const fileSystem = require("fs");
// use the module
fileSystem.stats("filepath",callbackFunction);
```

Everything that the module requires is loaded and ready for use when you receive the referance, this includes child modules, other dependencies, etc. When writing modules you specifically export your interface

```
export.doSomething = (thing) => { // do some to thing
```

**For the browser????? **

For the general browser environment there is `import` and `export` defined as part of the language. Unfortunately as yet not implemented by any browsers. Yet they are available via one of the many transpilers such as Babel.

You write your module exporting the interface and protecting the scope within your own namespace. When you write code you import the required modules and use the returned module referance to interface with it.

There are a wide variety of variations on this module approch and well worth investigating.

**The Module as a singleton**

The most basic approch is the singleton. This is a module as a js file that is referenced via the script tag. It contains an immediately invoked anonymous function that encapsulate the interface. It only exposes the namespace variable to the global scope.

```
const canvasInterface = (function(){
    // define private and protected objects
    var mycanvasColour = "Black";
    // define private functions
    function createCanvas(){ ...
    }

    // define the interface 
    const canvasStuff = {
         clearTheCanvas : function(){
         },
    }

    // return a referance to the interface 
    return canvasStuff;
}
```

You include it with

```
<script src="../mylibs/myCanvasModual.js"></script>
```

To use it (after onload)

```
canvasInterface.clearTheCanvas();
```

When the file loads the function is immediately executed and the interface becomes available via its defined namespace. What you do in the interface is up to you.

The primary important methodology is to only expose what is required to use the module and to never declare anything in the global name space that can be contained within the module. This will protect you from global namespace conflicts and keeps the internal state in your control (thus safe).

**The future looks good.**

Javascript is a bit of a mess in regards to modular design for now, but the modular approch is picking up and hopefully in the not too distant future we can enjoy a consistent and reliable means of linking our applications.